# Why does CODEIGNITER lost session after redirect to other controller by using "redirect" function?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am learning codeigniter. I am trying to code login system and after perfect login I want to redirect the page to another controller. After redirect, I can't get user session data. However when i manually go that page i can get the session data. Is there a solution?

what i have done for session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('userid', $user->user_id); //in login controller

echo "userid: ".$this->session->userdata('userid'); // in profile controller
```

codigniter version : 3.1.11
php version : 7.3.7

Note: Ive tried all the solution in the internet about "session.php"

EDIT:

```
  class Profilim extends CI_Controller
   {  
      public function index() 
      {          
         
         echo "profilim userid: ".$this->session->userdata('userid');
      } 
   } 


   class Giris extends CI_Controller
   {  

      public function index() 
      { 
         
         $this->load->model("GirisModel");



         if($this->input->post('giris')){

            $data["loginmessage"] = "";
            $data["login_status"] = false;

            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $result = $this->GirisModel->isUserExist($email,$password);
            

            if($result->num_rows()){
               $data["loginmessage"]="Giriş Başarılı!";
               $data["login_status"]=true;

               $user = $result->row();
               
               $this->session->set_userdata('userid', $user->user_id);

               
   
               /*Redirect the user to some internal controller’s method*/ 
               redirect('Profilim','refresh'); 

            }
            else{
               $data["loginmessage"]="Yanlış şifre veya kullanıcı adı!";
               $data["login_status"]=false;
            }
            $this->load->view("giris",$data);
         }else{
            $this->load->view("giris");
         }
         
      } 
   }
```

Comment: How to store session data in files or database?

Comment: i think in files

Comment: You think...??? What is set in config.php sessions section?

Comment: Yes i checked and said "files"

Comment: And did you load session library?

Comment: Yes in autoload.php. Also i think(got userid) session works when i call that page manually but it does not work when i use redrect

Comment: how does your redirect code look like?

Comment: it is like "redirect('Profilim','refresh'); "

Comment: In config.php the `$config['sess_save_path']` value is set to an exists path and this directory is writable for server user (www-data, nginx, etc...)?

Comment: Can you fetch the $_SESSION[] global var?

Comment: $config['sess_save_path'] value is NULL i tried a path i did not work

Comment: Can you fetch the $_SESSION[] global var? ---- I can get session when i call that page manually from search bar

Comment: $_SESSION['userid']; gives "undefined index error

Comment: Try to change session driver to database follows the instruction in official docs, and try again: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Comment: *$_SESSION['userid']; gives "undefined index error*, did you check value of `$user->user_id`, we have no idea, how that was generated! edit/add this to your your question please

Comment: yes $user->user_id works when i call the page from search bar manully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

If you did not set base_url in the config.php file it redirects page to http://[::1]/something so it deletes session if you change your base url to localhost it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (after backing up the named file): https://ganganga.in/2019/09/17/codeigniter-3-x-x-and-php-7-x-x-session-lost-while-redirect/

Codeigniter 3 based on PHP 5 but works to a limited extent with PHP 7.

Comment: Which Operating system and web server software did you used?

Comment: i am using debian and xampp